# Use jQuery to add an Active class to active tab elements depending on loaded Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**MY QUESTIONS** are:

- How can I add a class to an element unsing jQuery, or anything else for that matter, to the active tab?
- Have is so that the tab that dropdown is the one that contains the active tab & not always the Company one.

In sort I need to be able to have to active tab popup from the other tab and have it so the tab that drops down is the one that contains the active tab.

This is what it looks like:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

// Makes all other dropdowns vanish
  function slideAllUp(obj)
  {
     $(".hideothers").each(function(){
       
       if ($(this)[0] != obj[0])
       {
         $(this).hide(); //perform on all except self.
       }
     })
  }

// Sets active tab (adds class to active tab)
  $('.sidebar-menu li').on('click', function () {

      $(this).siblings().removeClass('clicked');
      $(this).addClass('clicked');


  });
  

$(".hideothers").hide();

// Account dropdown
    $(".slidingDiv_account").hide();
    $(".show_hide_account").show();
    
    $(".show_hide_account").click(function(){
    slideAllUp($(".slidingDiv_account"));
    $(".slidingDiv_account").slideDown();
    });

// Company dropdown
    $(".slidingDiv_company").show();
    $(".show_hide_company").show();
    // $(".hideothers").hide();
    
    $(".show_hide_company").click(function(){
    slideAllUp($(".slidingDiv_company"));
    $(".slidingDiv_company").slideDown();
    });

// Invest dropdown
    $(".slidingDiv_invest").hide();
    $(".show_hide_invest").show();
    // $(".hideothers").hide();
    
    $(".show_hide_invest").click(function(){
    slideAllUp($(".slidingDiv_invest"));
    $(".slidingDiv_invest").slideDown();
    });

  });
```

```css
ul.sidebar-menu , ul.sidebar-menu li ul.sub{
    margin: -2px 0 0;
    padding: 0;
}

ul.sidebar-menu {
    margin-top: 75px;
}

ul.sidebar-menu li a span{
    display: inline-block;
}

ul.sidebar-menu li a{
    color: #aeb2b7;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    padding: 15px 0 15px 10px;
    font-size: 12px;
    outline: none;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

ul.sidebar-menu li a.active, ul.sidebar-menu li a:hover, ul.sidebar-menu li a:focus {
    background: #68dff0;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;

    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}


ul.sidebar-menu li a i {
    font-size: 15px;
    padding-right: 6px;
}

ul.sidebar-menu li a:hover i, ul.sidebar-menu li a:focus i {
    color: #fff;
}

ul.sidebar-menu li a.active i {
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--sidebar start-->
      <aside>
      <!-- Start of Toggle -->
        <div id="sidebar"  class="nav-collapse ">
          <!-- sidebar menu start-->
          <ul class="sidebar-menu" id="nav-accordion">

          <div class="top_menu">
            <span class="show_hide_company">Company<i class="fa fa-briefcase"></i></span>
            <span class="show_hide_invest">Invest<i class="fa fa-line-chart"></i></span>
            <span class="show_hide_account">Account<i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
          </div><br>


          <!-- Account Dropdown --> 
            <div class="slidingDiv_account hideothers"> <!-- Start of toggle -->
              <li>
                <a href="/inbox">
                  <i class="fa fa-inbox"></i>
                  <span>Inbox</span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/users-companies">
                  <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                  <span>Users & Companies</span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/account">
                  <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
                  <span>Edit Account</span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/request-help">
                  <i class="fa fa-question"></i>
                  <span>Request & Help</span>
                </a>
              </li>
            </div> <!-- end of toggle -->


          <!-- Company Dropdown -->
            <div class="sub slidingDiv_company hideothers" style="display: block;"> <!-- Start of toggle -->
              
              <%if Company.where(:user_id => current_user.id).count==0 || current_user.premium%>
              <li>
                <a href="/companies/new">
                  <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                  <span>Start a Startup</span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <%end%>

              <%if Company.where(:user_id => current_user.id).count>=1%>
              <li>
                <a href="/companies">
                  <i class="fa fa-building"></i>
                  <%if Company.where(:user_id => current_user.id).count==1%>
                    <span>Company</span>
                  <%elsif Company.where(:user_id => current_user.id).count>1%>
                    <span>Companies</span>
                  <%end%>
                </a>
              </li>
              <%end%>
              
              <li>
                <a href="/trade">
                  <i class="fa fa-exchange"></i>
                  <span>Trade</span>
                </a>
              </li>

              <li>
                <a href="/profit-and-loss">
                  <i class="fa fa-list"></i>
                  <span>Profit & Loss</span>
                </a>
              </li>

              <li>
                <a href="/upgrade">
                  <i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i>
                  <span>Upgrade</span>
                </a>
              </li>

              <li>
                <a href="/employes/find">
                  <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                  <span>Find Employes</span>
                </a>
              </li>
              

            </div> <!-- end of toggle -->
          

          <!-- Invest Dropdown -->
            <div class="sub slidingDiv_invest hideothers" style="display: block;"> <!-- Start of toggle -->
              <li>
                <a href="/stock-market">
                  <i class="fa fa-line-chart"></i>
                  <span>Stock Market</span>
                </a>
              </li>

              <li>
                <a href="/find-investors">
                  <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                  <span>Find Investors</span>
                </a>
              </li>

              <li>
                <a href="/investments">
                  <i class="fa fa-list"></i>
                  <span>Invest</span>
                </a>
              </li>

              <li>
                <a href="/properties">
                  <i class="fa fa-bank"></i>
                  <span>Properties</span>
                </a>
              </li>

              <li>
                <a href="/advertisement">
                  <i class="fa fa-tv"></i>
                  <span>Advertisment</span>
                </a>
              </li>

            </div> <!-- end of toggle -->
          

            <li class="mt">
              <!--                       <a href="index.html"> -->
              <!--                           <i class="fa fa-search"></i> -->
              <!--                           <span>Browse Events</span> -->
            </a>
          </li>

        </ul>
        <!-- sidebar menu end-->
      </div>
    </aside>
    <!--sidebar end -->
```

Click on Company, Account and Invest to see the "dropdowns".

Note: When you click on a tab it loads a new page.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is add a click handler for `li` element and remove class active from all siblings and add class active to current clicked `li` item. This will make sure only the clicked link is active and rest do not contain active class

Here's jquery code to do this:

```
 $('.sidebar-menu li').on('click', function () {

      $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');


  });
```

Here is an working example(click on Run snippet) :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.menu li').on('click', function () {
      
      $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
      
      
  });
    
  });
```

```css
.active{
    
color:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="active">Menu Item 1</li>
    <li> Menu Item 2</li>
     <li> Menu Item 3</li>
     <li> Menu Item 4</li>
    
</ul>
```

[Here is the fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/gcsgsa2h/1/)

**UPDATE:**

Even for you menu, you can use same logic as explained above. All you really need to do is just changes some class names and same logic can be used

```
 $('.top_menu span').on('click', function () {

         $('.top_menu span').removeClass('active');
          $(this).addClass('active');


      });
```

Comment: What about for the dropdowns, how can I make is so that they all fade except for the one containing the active tab? Refer to the picture in the post (the three button dropdowns).

Comment: Other problem is that when I click it leads to another page therefore reseting the .active class leaving nothing active.

Comment: About the fade(i'm not sure what you mean by fade, exactly. I'm pretty sure you are not talking about `.fade()`); whatever your business/project specific requirement is(fade) do it in onclick function that i added. Just get the class and 'fade' checking your specific conditions.

Comment: problem 2 - dont add `active` to any any `li`, that way no class will stay active on page load. You add `active` class only `onclick` like i have shown in my answer. Just make sure your css class `active` exists and rest will be handled by onclick, you never enter the class inline for any `li`

Comment: Edited, added a snippet of what I have.

Comment: @Pabi Its still going to be the same all you need to do is change classnames. Check my edit. Its for the topmenu.